# Equations on numbers return NaN

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

The relevant bit of code is `var cEnergy = Math.min(pEnergy-pwrCons+cCharge,totalBattCap);`
I run `Logger.log(cEnergy)`  and it returns NaN. So I ran `Logger.log(typeof())` on cEnergy, pEnergy, pwrCons, cCharge, and totalBattCap and all return "number," so I'm not sure where the NaN error is coming from.

EDIT:
pEnergy, pwrCons, cCharge, and totalBattCap are all declared in the form of `var nCharge = ov.getRange("B5").getValue();` so they are pulled from cells on the sheet.

Comment: Although I admit it's somewhat confusing, the type of `NaN` is indeed "number". Although it does stand for "not a number", really it means what you get when you do an operation where a number was expected but something went wrong. For example a division by zero returns `NaN`. As for what exactly has gone wrong, we'd need to see your code. Perhaps one of the variables is `undefined` (which becomes to `NaN` when co-erced to a number, and the operations you're doing will coerce the values to numbers).

Comment: I ran the Logger.log(typeof()) to check that. But I edited to add the code form for each.

Comment: your edit doesn't help me figure out what the actual values are. Try just `console.log(pEnergy)`, and the same for each other value. You'll surely find one which is `undefined` or perhaps some other unexpected value. This is debugging 101, really.

Comment: `console.log` each of the variables right before your call to `Math.min`. It's likely that one of them was based on an undefined value (which is coerced to NaN in a numeric context), or that you did an operation that returned a NaN (e.g. division by 0).

Comment: Ah! Thank you. I'd always used just the Logger.log() so I was getting less debug info. I found it in a line much higher.

Answer (score 0):

I think this was already asked here [enter link description here][Math.min returns NaN]

Comment: I'm not sending in an array, so I'm not sure there.